# Reloading a single div in an html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div on the left side of my page containing a nav. However, when the user clicks a link it only changes content on the right side of my page. Is there a way to only load the right side when the link is clicked? For example when a link in "navPanel" is clicked, "contentPanel" should reload with the content on that link.

```
<nav id="navPanel">
   <a>link 1</a>
   <a>link 2</a>
   <a>link 3</a>
</nav>

<div id="contentPanel">
   <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to provide code samples, html and javascript.  Otherwise I am only guessing.

Comment: Maybe have a read of the guidelines on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add a code sample so people can help you.

Comment: With the rest of these guys, question needs more info, but suggest looking at AJAX to load new content.

Comment: [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX)

Comment: This is an acceptable "extra" feature for a site, but please make sure your links (link2, link3, etc) work correctly when typed directly into a browser.  Also, you're going to run into trouble with folks who want to click on, say, link2 and then bookmark that page in their browser.

Comment: Okay, I did not think of the bookmarking. So far the links work as expected, although I am still working on it, thanks for the remarks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can use the jQuery function called load().

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$( function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#navPanel a", function(){
        var link = $(this).attr('rel');  
        $("#contentPanel").load(link+" #contentPanel > *");
    });
});
</script>

<nav id="navPanel">
   <a rel='link.html'>link 1</a>
   <a rel='link.html'>link 2</a>
   <a rel='link.html'>link 3</a>
</nav>

<div id="contentPanel">
   <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: He used javascript as a tag. So that's that for a starter. Also, I said I was going to edit with a working example. Just waiting on the HTML to work this up. Loading some HTML in a div upon click is pretty much a jQuery basic feature.

Comment: I do know basic javascript, currently trying to teach it to myself, I will look at jQuery as well.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'll look into jQuery tonight and apply this!

Comment: Np accept the answer and let me know if you specific questions.